# Javascript validation and Zend_Form

Tags: javascript, zend-framework, zend-form

I have extended Zend_Form to create my custom form that I will reuse on some pages of my site.
For this form I also created some JavaScript validation based upon jquery.

What I would like to do is add this JavaScript validation for the form in the sub-classed Zend_Form. So every time the form is called the JavaScript gets initiated as well.

In a view script you can use $this->headScript()->appendFile('/js/val.js') and than use echo $this->headScript() in the layout. But headScript() is to my knowledge not possible in Zend_Form.

How can I use headscript in Zend_Form or is their a alternative 'better' approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
$this->getView();
```

inside the form to get a reference to your view (via the view renderer). Use the view to access your view helpers then:

```
$this->getView()->headScript()->appendFile('/js/val.js');
```

I may add that I actually don't like this approach as it ties your form to the view, but it's the easiest and fastest way to do what you try to do.

Comment: Stefan, which approach do you think is better to store the javascript validation together with the form?

Comment: Perhaps some view helper, that creates the form and injects the javascript into the view would reduce this coupling. But I don't think that †his is worth the effort, if you don't use your forms outside a view context (e.g. some developers suggest to use forms inside the model to do the validation there).